# I want to update my node.js so I can run react

Tags: node.js

```
PS C:\Users\dj waterside\Documents\React> npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@9.2.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:  !win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual os: win32


npm install 
npm install -g n
error
n latest
```

Comment: The error says that the library doesn't support win32, but you are trying to install it on win32 https://www.npmjs.com/package/n
Just go to https://nodejs.org/en and download the newest version

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `nvm`, then write in terminal:

```bash
nvm use --lts
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [NVM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm), by installing it you can switch to diffrent node versions -->
npm i nvm